# Display images from two dropdown menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-select

Running into a bit of a brick wall here with my limited coding knowledge.

I have a dropdown menu which displays images upon selection, that's all well and good. How do I add a second dropdown and corresponding image without the dropdowns feeding into/interfering with each other?

Ideally I want to end up with two dropdown boxes side by side - each reading from the same set of image variables - then two images side by side beneath them.

Here is the code for the single working one;
Head contains:

```
var linkData = [
  ['http://i.imgur.com/4ECkKqG.png'],
  ['http://i.imgur.com/98zZKAm.png'],
]
  //preload the pics
  var picO = new Array();
  for(i=0; i < linkData.length; i++){
  picO[i] = new Image();
  picO[i].src = linkData[i][0];
}

function show(val) {
  document.getElementById('picture').src = picO[val-1].src;
}
window.onload=function(){
  show(1);
}
```

body

```html
<div>
    <select onchange="show(this.value);">
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <a><img id="picture" src="" /></a> 
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, could you please provide a jsfiddle of what you have working and showing where it fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all using `picO` array and `new Image()` to create new Images and storing them in this array is useless here just get rid of it, then just use a function where you pass the current dropdown and the `id` of the target `img`, and call it on each select change event.

This is a working snippet:

```js
var linkData = [
  ['http://i.imgur.com/4ECkKqG.png'],
  ['http://i.imgur.com/98zZKAm.png'],
]

function changeImage(select, id) {
  var img = document.getElementById(id);
  img.src = linkData[(select.value) - 1][0];
  return false;
}
```

```html
<select id="select1" onchange="changeImage(this, 'image1')">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select><br/>
<img id="image1" src="http://i.imgur.com/4ECkKqG.png" />

<br>
<select id="select2" onchange="changeImage(this, 'image2')">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select><br/>
<img id="image2" src="http://i.imgur.com/4ECkKqG.png" />
```

Comment: Great, Glad it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if this is what you meant to do but I made you a fiddle with the code. Hope is good.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xf2pq/165/).

And the code is this:

```js
function select1() {
    var img = document.getElementById("image1");
    img.src = this.value;
    return false;
}
document.getElementById("select1").onchange = select1;

function select2() {
    var img = document.getElementById("image2");
    img.src = this.value;
    return false;
}
document.getElementById("select2").onchange = select2;
```

```html
<img id="image1" src="http://i.imgur.com/4ECkKqG.png" />
<select id="select1">
    <option value="http://i.imgur.com/4ECkKqG.png">Img 1</option>
    <option value="http://i.imgur.com/98zZKAm.png">Img2</option>
</select>
<br>
<img id="image2" src="http://i.imgur.com/4ECkKqG.png" />
<select id="select2">
    <option value="http://i.imgur.com/4ECkKqG.png">Img 1</option>
    <option value="http://i.imgur.com/98zZKAm.png">Img2</option>
</select>
```